# y position issue for background images via css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, parallax

I have implemented a parallax scrolling effect based on a tutorial I found. The effect works great. However, when I specify the background images, I am unable to control the y (vertical) axis. This is causing problems because I'm trying to set locations on multiple layered images.

Any thoughts on what's causing the problem?

Here is one external script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#nav').localScroll(800);

//.parallax(xPosition, speedFactor, outerHeight) options:
//xPosition - Horizontal position of the element
//inertia - speed to move relative to vertical scroll. Example: 0.1 is one tenth the speed of scrolling, 2 is twice the speed of scrolling
//outerHeight (true/false) - Whether or not jQuery should use it's outerHeight option to determine when a section is in the viewport
$('#mainimagewrapper').parallax("50%", 1.3);
$('#secondaryimagewrapper').parallax("50%", 0.5);
$('.image2').parallax("50%", -0.1);
$('#aboutwrapper').parallax("50%", 1.7);
$('.image4').parallax("50%", 1.5);
```

})

This is another external script:

```
(function( $ ){
var $window = $(window);
var windowHeight = $window.height();

$window.resize(function () {
    windowHeight = $window.height();
});

$.fn.parallax = function(xpos, speedFactor, outerHeight) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var getHeight;
    var firstTop;
    var paddingTop = 0;

    //get the starting position of each element to have parallax applied to it      
    $this.each(function(){
        firstTop = $this.offset().top;
    });

    if (outerHeight) {
        getHeight = function(jqo) {
            return jqo.outerHeight(true);
        };
    } else {
        getHeight = function(jqo) {
            return jqo.height();
        };
    }

    // setup defaults if arguments aren't specified
    if (arguments.length < 1 || xpos === null) xpos = "50%";
    if (arguments.length < 2 || speedFactor === null) speedFactor = 0.1;
    if (arguments.length < 3 || outerHeight === null) outerHeight = true;

    // function to be called whenever the window is scrolled or resized
    function update(){
        var pos = $window.scrollTop();              

        $this.each(function(){
            var $element = $(this);
            var top = $element.offset().top;
            var height = getHeight($element);

            // Check if totally above or totally below viewport
            if (top + height < pos || top > pos + windowHeight) {
                return;
            }

            $this.css('backgroundPosition', xpos + " " + Math.round((firstTop - pos) * speedFactor) + "px");
        });
    }       

    $window.bind('scroll', update).resize(update);
    update();
};
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the CSS for one section:

```
#aboutwrapper {
background-image: url(../images/polaroid.png);
background-position: 50% 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
color: white;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

#aboutwrapper .image4 {
background: url(../images/polaroid2.png) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

.image3{
margin: 0 auto;
min-width: 970px;
overflow: auto;
width: 970px; 
}
```

Both of these are being called to achieve the parallax scrolling. I really just want to more specifically control the background image locations. I've tried messing with the CSS background position and I've messed with the first javascript snippet as well. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick shot, have you tried actually placing the images, either in a div or just using the img src tag to actually move the element rather than manipulating the y axis of a background image?

Comment: I assumed I had to keep the structure intact from the tutorial in order to achieve the parallax effect. So I've just been manipulating what it contained.

Comment: well, I would have to get more into it, but you have 50% spec'd in the css for the y position, fixed is in there...the jquery would need to address the css property background instead of the element with the background....at least at a quick glance that what may be the issue. Do you have a link to the tutorial you followed?

Comment: When I rip this piece of the jquery out, I can use css to position and it works. But, I lose my scrolling effect. 

$('#aboutwrapper').parallax("50%", 1.7);

Comment: I'm assuming the code above is pulling the x position and specifying the speed of the scroll. Is there a way to add in the vertical position with that?

Comment: I've been digging some more and I believe that this code ($('#aboutwrapper').parallax("50%", 1.7);) is the culprit. I did some testing in chrome's Inspect element and the css specified background position is being overwritten with that javascript. I have no idea what to do. Anything I do to this line breaks the parallax effect.

Comment: well, after looking at this a little more, it doesn't appear you're going to be able to specify a specific coordinate/position with the background position because the sequence.js plug-in is using that parameter as a means of multiplication, not position. So you might have to alter the starting positions or rethink how you will achieve the parallex effect.